# Change .NET Runtime without full server app domain recycle?

Tags: iis-6, asp.net

Is there any way I can change the .NET Runtime of a website without full server app domain recycle?

It appears when changing the .NET version in the configuration properties, all of our app domains appear to be restarting, but stop and must manually started. This is annoying. Appcmd.exe would be a great solution, but this is only available on IIS 7 :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is no... when you switch .Net runtime, it cycles everything within that app pool.